# Android - How to write to /mnt/local/

Tags: android, file-io

what i've to do with my app is to download some files and write in /mnt/local/.

This is what i try:

```
String baseDir = Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/mnt/local/mydir" //mydir exists.
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(baseDir);
```

What i get is:

```
11-08 18:40:29.799: W/System.err(26464): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/mnt/local/htdocs: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-08 18:40:29.800: W/System.err(26464):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
11-08 18:40:29.801: W/System.err(26464):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
11-08 18:40:29.802: W/System.err(26464):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
11-08 18:40:29.803: W/System.err(26464):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
11-08 18:40:29.803: W/System.err(26464):    at support.Support.downloadFile(Support.java:45)
11-08 18:40:29.804: W/System.err(26464):    at task.OfflineUpdate.updateFromArchive(OfflineUpdate.java:84)
11-08 18:40:29.805: W/System.err(26464):    at task.OfflineUpdate.update(OfflineUpdate.java:77)
11-08 18:40:29.805: W/System.err(26464):    at task.OfflineUpdate.access$3(OfflineUpdate.java:74)
11-08 18:40:29.805: W/System.err(26464):    at task.OfflineUpdate$1.run(OfflineUpdate.java:59)
11-08 18:40:29.806: W/System.err(26464):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-08 18:40:29.807: W/System.err(26464): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-08 18:40:29.808: W/System.err(26464):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-08 18:40:29.810: W/System.err(26464):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-08 18:40:29.810: W/System.err(26464):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
11-08 18:40:29.812: W/System.err(26464):    ... 9 more
```

i don't know how to access to that dir.. can someone enlighten me?

Comment: what's the value of your variable `baseDir` after assignment? isn't / the root directory?

Comment: as you can see is not "/".. is "/system/"...

Comment: `mydir` is directory not file, so how can you write to dir??

Comment: @Astor damn! it was so simple.. ur right! mydir is a dir... and there i need a file :) thanks! so much.. if u put ur comment in an answer i'll accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (from name) that `mydir` is directory (not file), so you can't write to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, except perhaps on a rooted device with the app running as superuser, as otherwise you have no read or write access there.

To get rid of the `/system/` prefix, delete `Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+` from your code.

Comment: the app must run on some rooted device! but if i leave only /mnt/local/mydir it gives me the same error..

Comment: @JackTurky: Make sure your app is running as superuser. Beyond that, I have no advice, as this is not something ordinary Android SDK developers try to do.